# WP How to Create Link for Custom Template?

Tags: php, wordpress

I cannot get working my code and I thought that best way is asking here.

so as on the title

Im looking to create a function (link for a specific template file) for my template-contact.php

Tried to do with this function wich I found in another topic but it didnt work.

```
function get_contact_page() {
    $contact_page = get_pages(
        array(
            'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'meta_value' => 'template-contact.php'
        )
    );
    $contact_id = $showcase_page[0]->ID;
    echo get_permalink( $contact_id );
}
```

but when I use

```
<a href="<?php echo get_contact_page(); ?>" class="widget" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-title="CONTATTO"><span
                                class="ico ico-phone-btn"></span></a>
```

does nothing.
Thanks for all your help

Comment: you mean to change this with your code right? `echo get_permalink( $contact_id );` to `var_dump( $contact_page );` this changed the link to `http://localhost/array(0) {}` if I use $contact_id in your code link returns to `http://localhost/NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_pages()` has an issue with `meta_key` and `meta_value` parameters. I recommend using [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead:

```
function get_contact_page() {
    $query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'meta_value' => 'template-contact.php',
            'fields' => 'ids',
        )
    );

    return $query->have_posts() ? get_permalink( $query->posts[0] ) : '#';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but Im very confused so my codes are in functions.php and Im looking only to create e default link for my template-contact.php I have added your function but now everything is broken after menu section where is contact icon in header with link `<?php echo get_contact_page(); ?> ` after this everything is broken :(

Comment: Yes but maybe Im wrong because I dont have a big experience so is there any way to dedect the custom template slug via function?

Comment: I mean to create something like buddypress for example in a wordpress with buddypress installed to put the link of registration page I use bp_signup_page() Im looking to make same with my contact page this is all :(

Comment: OMG I m so idiot the wordpress supports this without writing any function and you are right but as I see Im so stupid because I was trying something wich is for another work as I see there is a simple way using `<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'templates/contact' ) ) ?>` Guys thanks to all for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo get_permalink( $archive_id );
```

change to

```
return get_permalink( $archive_id );
```

Comment: tried but same is giving a post link instead of the contact page